# Are Lissajous figures SHM(s)?

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, terminology, definition

Are [Lissajous figures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lissajous_curve) SHM(s)? I have been studying perpendicular superposition of SHM(s). And i understand that 2 shm having same angular frequency and differed by phase pi/2 when superimposed perpendiculary gives a motion that represents circle. But now is this resultant motion  can also be considered a shm? and why?
Also somewhere in my notes i read that a symmetric Lissajous figures represents a shm. Is this true?

Answer (score 0):

Lissajous figures can be defined as the **trajectories** of a point performing a motion that is the **composition (vector sum) of harmonic motions along 2 orthogonal directions**,

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{r}(t) = a_x \cos(\omega_x t) \mathbf{\hat{x}} + a_y \cos(\omega_y t + \phi) \mathbf{\hat{y}}
\end{equation}

Depending on the ratio of the angular frequencies and the phase shift you get different curves. As you mentioned in your question:

- same angular frequencies, $\omega_x = \omega_y$, and no phase shift, $\phi = 0$: segment. Explicitly,
  \begin{equation}
  \mathbf{r}(t) = a_x \cos(\omega t) \mathbf{\hat{x}} + a_y \cos(\omega t) \mathbf{\hat{y}} \ ,
  \end{equation}
  and defining a new parameter $v = \cos(\omega t)$, $v \in [-1, 1]$,
  \begin{equation}\begin{cases}
    x(v) = a_x v \\
    y(v) = a_y v \ ,
  \end{cases}\end{equation}
  we get the parametric equation of the segment, with slope $\frac{a_y}{a_x}$.
- same angular frequency, $\omega_x = \omega_y$, and phase shift equal to $\phi = \pi/2$: ellipse or circle (if $a_x = a_y$). Explicitly writing the coordinates,
  \begin{equation}\begin{cases}
     x(t) = a_x \cos(\omega t) \\
     y(t) = - a_y \sin(\omega t) \ ,
  \end{cases}\end{equation}
  i.e. the parametric equation of an ellipse drawn in the clockwise direction.

Answer (score 0):

Lissajous figures are the sum of two simple harmonic motions at right angles to one another.

Here is a link to a [GeoGebra simulation](https://www.geogebra.org/m/nsgkxuyn) of such an addition.

$A$ and $B$ are the amplitudes of the shms, $a$ and $b$ and $\delta$ is the initial phase angle between them.

[image]

Only when the two frequencies are the same and the phase angle $\delta=0^\circ$ or $\delta = 180^\circ$ is the resultant motion simple harmonic.

There are some nice animation on [this website](https://extremelearning.com.au/lissajous-curves/).

Answer (score 0):

SHM may be defined as motion in which the acceleration is proportional to the displacement from a fixed point, but in the opposite direction. A further restriction, sometimes imposed, is that the motion is in a straight line.

According to the unrestricted definition, motion of a point that describes a Lissajous figure generated by sinusoidal displacements *of the same frequency* at right angles to each other is indeed SHM. Details follow; for straight line motion put $\epsilon=0\ \text{or}\ ±\pi.$

Suppose
$$\vec x = A \cos{\omega t}\ \vec i\ \ \ \ \ \text{and}\ \ \ \ \ \vec y = B \cos(\omega t+\epsilon)\vec j$$
Then
$$\ddot{\vec x} = -A \omega^2\cos{\omega t}\ \vec i=-\omega^2 \vec x\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{and}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ddot{\vec y} = -B\omega^2 \cos(\omega t+\epsilon)\vec j=-\omega^2\vec y$$
The displacement is the vector sum of the component displacements, and the acceleration is the vector sum of the component accelerations, so adding the last two equations,
$$\ddot{\vec x}+\ddot{\vec y}=-\omega^2(\vec x+\vec y)$$
that is
$$\ddot{\overbrace{(\vec x +\vec y)}}=-\omega^2(\vec x+\vec y)$$
Arguably the last step is the subtle one. It relies on the linearity of the differentiation operation.

It's easy to see that if the two component SHMs have different frequencies, their resultant won't be SHM: we can't take a single $\omega$ outside the bracket in my third line of maths.